# How to point VitualHost configuation to the web application in Apache2.4

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, apache2.4

We are hosting a Magento site in Ubuntu server.

Magento application is in `/var/www/html/magento` and I created the `magento.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/magento.conf`.

magento.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
        <Directory /var/www/html/magento>
                Allowoverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I am trying to open the application by using `mysite.com` in the browser, it is showing apache webpage.

But when I am trying `mysite.com/magento` it is showing only the home page without CSS and all other pages are 404 not found error.

In the `apache.conf`, magento.conf file is included.

Comment: Did you enable the site with `sudo a2ensite magento`? The creates a symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. You should not need to include the config manually in `apache.conf`, there is already an include `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` at the end of the file. Reload the server with `sudo service apache2 reload` afterwards.

Comment: Yes I enabled the site with ```sudo a2ensite magento``` and I mean the magento.conf file is included using ```IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf``` and finally restarted the service. Still the same issue I am facing.

Comment: Hmm. Disable the default site (probably `sudo a2dissite 000-default`)? Don't forget to add an `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` to your `magento.conf`, copy & paste the lines from the default config.

Comment: I did ```sudo a2dissite 000-deafault``` and now getting ```Internal server error```

Comment: What do you see in your error.log? Additionally run `apachectl configtest` to check for syntax errors.

Comment: Error log is ```/var/www/html/magento/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration``` and configtest showing ```Syntax OK```

Comment: Thanks @Freddy, Now it is working. I did ```a2enmod headers``` and restarted the apache.